# Check the length of the string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to write a program that inputs a string (that is actually a sentence) and an array. The function should check if the values in the array are the lengths of each word in the string.

**Example 1:**
This is an example. (The array should be: [4,2,2,7].

**Example 2:**
Space... The final frontier... (The array should be: [5,3,5,8]).

I'm struggling with a few things:

1. How do I check if the length of a word is equal to the value in the array **without putting the lengths in another array**?
2. Why does my code register symbols like ('.','!'...) as words?
3. Why is my `lengthofstring` always 0? Is my `if-statement` wrong?

Here is what I have written so far.

```
int checklength(const char *str,int array[],int n)
{
    int i,j=0,start=0,end,lengthofword,lengthofstring,isittrue=0;
    while(*(str+lengthofstring)!='\0')
    {
        lengthofstring++;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<lengthofstring+1;i++)
    {
        if((*(str+i)>=32 && *(str+i)<=64) || (*(str+i)>=91 && *(str+i)<=96) || (*(str+i)>=123 && *(str+i)<=126))
        {
            end=i;
            lengthofword=end-start; //Why is my lengthofword 0 here?
            
            //Here is what I tried for checking if value is in array:
            j++;
            while(j<n)
            {
                if(array[j]==lengthofword)
                {
                    isittrue=1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
       start=i+1;  
    }
    return isittrue;
}
```

Comment: You should ask one question.  Use char literals 'a', ' ' instead of ascii codes directly.  lengthofstring is uninitialized so your code is undefined behavior (game over).  Prefer [] to *() format.  Former is usually easier to read.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the std strings functions?  strlen, strchr etc?  Please supply a [mre], ie how are you calling this?

Comment: @AllanWind I'm trying not to use any functions from <stdlib.h> or <string.h>.

Answer (score 1):

1. You check one word at a time and exit when the first length test fails.
2. `*(str+i)>=32 && *(str+i)<=64)` matches those symbols and you don't exclude it elsewhere.
3. You operate on uninitialized data which is undefined behavior.

Here is how I would write this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_word_len(const char *str, size_t n) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for(; i < n; i++)
        if(!isalpha(str[i]))
            return 0;
    return !isalpha(str[i]);
}

int is_str_lens(const char *str, size_t n, size_t array[n]) {
    // Consider adding checks along these lines:
    // assert(str);
    // assert(*str);
    // assert(n);
    // assert(array);
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    for(; str[offset] && i < n; i++) {
        while(str[offset] && !isalpha(str[offset])) offset++;
        if(!is_word_len(&str[offset], array[i]))
            return 0;
        offset += array[i];
    }
    while(str[offset] && !isalpha(str[offset])) offset++;
    return i == n && !str[offset];
}

int main() {
    struct {
        char *str;
        size_t n;
        size_t *array;
    } tests[] = {
        { "This is an example.", 4, (size_t []) { 4, 2, 2, 7} },
        { "Space... The final frontier...", 4, (size_t []) { 5, 3, 5, 8 } },
        { "...Space... The final frontier...", 4, (size_t []) { 5, 3, 5, 8 } },
        { "Space...", 2, (size_t []) { 5, 2 } },
        { "Babies x", 1, (size_t []) { 6 } }
        { "This", 2, (size_t []) { 2, 2 } }
    };
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof tests / sizeof *tests; i++) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", tests[i].str, is_str_lens(tests[i].str, tests[i].n, tests[i].array));
    }
}
```

and output:

```
This is an example.: 1
Space... The final frontier...: 1
...Space... The final frontier...: 1
Space...: 0
Babies x: 0
This: 0
```

If you don't want to use `isalpha()` then re-implement along these lines:

```
int my_isalpha(int c) {
   return
      c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ||
      c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to read and too complicated. You have very handy standard functions which can help you with your task.

```
int checklength(const char *str, const size_t *array, const size_t n, const char *delim)
{
    int isittrue = 1;
    size_t cpos = 0;
    char *token;
    char *modifStr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    if(modifStr)
    {
        strcpy(modifStr, str);
        token = strtok(modifStr, delim);
        while(token)
        {
            if(array[cpos] != strlen(token))
            {
                isittrue = 0;
                break;
            }
            cpos++;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
    }
    else return -1;
    free(modifStr);
    return isittrue && cpos == n;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", checklength("This is an example.", (size_t[]){4,2,2,7}, 4, " ."));
    printf("%d\n", checklength("Space... The final frontier...", (size_t[]){5,3,5,8}, 4, " ."));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xnf6sK1cx

You can improve this function by adding parameter checks, checking if number of words is not larger than the number of elements of the array etc. But I have left it for you....

Answer (score 0):

I had great trouble following OP's code and so offer a simplification.

Walk the array *once*.  No need for a prior `strlen()`.

Look for word beginnings by noting the transition from non-word to word.

Once in a word, find its end.  The one-past-end minus start is the word length.

Use `isalpha()` to test if a character is a letter.  Best to use *unsigned* characters.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int checklength(const char *str, int array[], int n) {
  const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char*) str;
  int i = 0;
  while (*str) {
    unsigned char ch = *s;
    if (isalpha(ch)) {
      if (i >= n) {
        return true; // no more words to test
      }
      // Beginning of a word
      const unsigned char *next = s + 1;
      while (isalpha(*next)) {
        next++;
      }
      // next now points 1 past the end of the word.
      // Test word length.
      if (next - s != array[i]) {
        return false;  // Word length does not match
      }
      i++;
      s = next;
    } else {
      s++;
    }
  }
  return true; // All words match
}
```